# How to verify AWS SES email address if I can't yet receive email?

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I'm setting up AWS SES for my node.js website. How do I verify a sending address if I can't receive the verification email at that address?

I don't need to be receiving email there, I'll use reply-to addresses, but I do need to verify the address so I can send email.

Thoughts?

**Update** Also, do I need to verify email addresses I play to put in the Reply-To header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need SNS notification services.

When you enable SES service and register `domain` or `sender email address`, there are three options of [SNS](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/) notifications.

```
Bounce Notifications SNS Topic:none

Complaint Notifications SNS Topic:none

Delivery Notifications SNS Topic:none
```

Enable some of them, or all. In your case, should be Bounce and complaint notifications.

1. Go to SNS service to create the related topic
2. Subscription the notify mailbox
3. active the options in SES

Comment: Thanks so much, this helps. I ended up using a domain alias in Google Apps, which solves this problem (and others) in a very different way, but this is exactly what I was looking for. AWS is such a big universe of services. I'm still learning.